# MACD+BB pinescript combining strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How to combine BB cross with macd cross I combined them but the strategy only showed me bb cross and macd cross in the same bar , sometimes macd cross happens after bb cross and that is what I want to detect

How to combine BB cross with macd cross I combined them but the strategy only showed me bb cross and macd cross in the same bar , sometimes macd cross happens after bb cross and that is what ant to detect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
//@version=4
strategy("BB MACD Cross Strategy")

// Define the BB inputs
length = input(20, minval=1)
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)

// Define the MACD inputs
fast_length = input(12)
slow_length = input(26)
signal_length = input(9)

// Get the BB bands and MACD values
bb_upper = bbands(close, length, mult)["upper"]
bb_lower = bbands(close, length, mult)["lower"]
[macd_line, signal_line, _] = ta.macd(close, fast_length, slow_length, signal_length)

// Check for BB and MACD crossovers
bb_cross = crossover(close, bb_upper) or crossunder(close, bb_lower)
macd_cross = crossover(macd_line, signal_line) or crossunder(signal_line, macd_line)

// Enter long position if both BB and MACD crosses occur and MACD cross comes after BB cross
if (bb_cross and macd_cross and barssince(bb_cross) < barssince(macd_cross))
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Exit position if MACD crosses in the opposite direction
if (macd_cross and barssince(macd_cross) < barssince(bb_cross))
    strategy.close("Long")
```

Comment: Error at 14:0 Could not find function or function reference 'bbands'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).